# How do I change HSL color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

This is the example I want to do. Is it possible to use the two color #00809C and #142E76 from left to right, how can I do?
https://codepen.io/rodzyk/pen/mdxvQby

```js
const gradateLineTemplate = (deg: number, hue: number) =>
    `<line data-deg="${deg}" class="active" style="--deg: ${deg}deg; --h: ${hue}" x1="300" y1="30" x2="300" y2="70" />`;
```

Here is js code i find the way to change color,but it couldn't use specify color,just only adjust the degree to change color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way, converting your colors to HSL and interpolating all three values separately. https://codepen.io/BoppreH/pen/yLxdvrP

Change the SCSS to accept all three of H, S, and L values for each line, instead of just H and S:

```
.gradate {
    line {
        --deg: 0deg;
        --h: 135;
        --s: 10%;
        --a: 0.2;
        --l: 55%;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-width: 10px;
        stroke: hsla(var(--h), var(--s), var(--l), var(--a));
```

Convert your two colors to HSL (done manually here, but you could automate):

```
// H between 0-360, and S and L between 0 and 100.
const START_HSL = [191, 100, 31]; // #00809c
const END_HSL = [224, 71, 27]; // #142e76
```

Move the `mapBetween` and `getRangePercent` to the top, because we'll need them for the interpolation.

Change how the lines are created.

```
const gradateLineTemplate = (deg: number, h: number, s: number, l: number) =>
    `<line data-deg="${deg}" class="active" style="--deg: ${deg}deg; --h: ${h}deg; --s: ${s}%; --l: ${l}%;" x1="300" y1="30" x2="300" y2="70" />`;

let gradateLines = ``;
const Q = DEG_RANGE / STEP;
for (let i = DEG_RANGE * -1; i <= DEG_RANGE; i += Q) {
    const p = (100 * (i + DEG_RANGE)) / (2 * DEG_RANGE);
    const h = getRangeNumber(p, START_HSL[0], END_HSL[0]);
    const s = getRangeNumber(p, START_HSL[1], END_HSL[1]);
    const l = getRangeNumber(p, START_HSL[2], END_HSL[2]);
    gradateLines += gradateLineTemplate(i, h, s, l);
}
```

And finally, change `setValue` so that the ball cursor gets a matching color:

```
function setValue(v) {
    deactiveAll();
    active(v);
    slider.style.setProperty("--deg", `${v}deg`);
    sliderShadow.style.setProperty("--deg", `${v}deg`);
    const p = (100 * (v + DEG_RANGE)) / (2 * DEG_RANGE);
    console.log(p);
    slider.style.setProperty(
        "--h",
        `${getRangeNumber(p, START_HSL[0], END_HSL[0])}deg`
    );
    slider.style.setProperty(
        "--s",
        `${getRangeNumber(p, START_HSL[1], END_HSL[1])}%`
    );
    slider.style.setProperty(
        "--l",
        `${getRangeNumber(p, START_HSL[2], END_HSL[2])}%`
    );
}
```